# awk to print part of an array in shell

Tags: shell, awk

Hello I have a text file with hundreds of lines. Here's a sample.

```
Array 1 - JVMAZURE,/www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE/ReceiveResponseFromAzureDEV,com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure

JVM - JVMAZURE
Node - com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure
Jar - /www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE/ReceiveResponseFromAzureDEV
AXIOM.SVAP.IN
LOG.XML.INPUT
SERVADMIN.ERROR
SERVADMIN.INPUT
TIMEOUT.IN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Array 2 - JVMAZURE,/www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE/ReceiveResponse,com.azure.RecivedResponse

JVM - JVMAZURE
Node - com.azure.RecivedResponse
Jar - /www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE/ReceiveResponseDEV
AXIOM.SVAP.IN
EXCEPTION.QUEUE
SERVADMIN.ERROR
SERVADMIN.INPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Array 3 - JVMAZURE1,/www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE1/SendMessageToAzureCloudDEV,com.azure.SendMessageToAzureCloud

JVM - JVMAZURE1
Node - com.azure.SendMessageToAzureCloud
Jar - /www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE1/SendMessageToAzureCloudDEV
AZURE.SVAP.IN
LOG.XML.INPUT
AXIOM.SERVADMIN.OUTPUT
SERVADMIN.ERROR
SB.OUT
TIMEOUT.IN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Array 4 - JVMAZURE2,/www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE2/SendMessageFromAzureCloudDEV,com.azure.SendMessageFromAzureCloud

JVM - JVMAZURE2
Node - com.azure.SendMessageFromAzureCloud
Jar - /www/deploy/DEV/JVMAZURE2/SendMessageFromAzureCloudDEV
AZURE.SVAP.IN
SERVADMIN.ERROR
TIMEOUT.IN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to grep or awk for the lines/patterns below the Jar and trying to print the JVM,Node and that line I am searching for.

So, if i am searching for `AXIOM.SVAP.IN`, I want the output to be

```
JVMAZURE,com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure,AXIOM.SVAP.IN
JVMAZURE,com.azure.RecivedResponse,AXIOM.SVAP.IN
```

or if i am searching for `SERVADMIN.ERROR` I want the output to be

```
  JVMAZURE,com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure,SERVADMIN.ERROR
  JVMAZURE,com.azure.RecivedResponse,SERVADMIN.ERROR
  JVMAZURE1,com.azure.SendMessageToAzureCloud,SERVADMIN.ERROR
  JVMAZURE2,com.azure.SendMessageFromAzureCloud,SERVADMIN.ERROR
```

I have tried with awk but have not got any consistent results.

`cat AZURE.txt|awk -v OFS=, -v r="^'|'$" '/SERVADMIN.ERROR/ { p=$NF; gsub(r,"",p) } /EG/ { e=$NF } /Flow/ {f=$NF; gsub(r,"",f); print e,f,p }'`

is yiedling me

```
JVMAZURE,com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure,
JVMAZURE,com.azure.RecivedResponse,SERVADMIN.ERROR
JVMAZURE1,com.azure.SendMessageToAzureCloud,SERVADMIN.ERROR
JVMAZURE2,com.azure.SendMessageFromAzureCloud,SERVADMIN.ERROR
```

And the same result with the line/pattern changed if i search for `AXIOM.SVAP.IN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have name->value pairs in your input it's best to create an array (`f[]` below) to hold that relationship and then you can just access the values by their names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" - "; OFS="," }
(Jar in f) && ($0 == tgt) { print f["JVM"], f["Node"], $0 }
{ f[$1] = $2; prev = $1 }
/^-+$/ { delete f }

$ awk -v tgt='AXIOM.SVAP.IN' -f tst.awk file
JVMAZURE,com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure,AXIOM.SVAP.IN
JVMAZURE,com.azure.RecivedResponse,AXIOM.SVAP.IN

$ awk -v tgt='SERVADMIN.ERROR' -f tst.awk file
JVMAZURE,com.azure.ReceiveResponseFromAzure,SERVADMIN.ERROR
JVMAZURE,com.azure.RecivedResponse,SERVADMIN.ERROR
JVMAZURE1,com.azure.SendMessageToAzureCloud,SERVADMIN.ERROR
JVMAZURE2,com.azure.SendMessageFromAzureCloud,SERVADMIN.ERROR
```

Comment: This only works for AXIOM.SVAP.IN. If i have the pattern as SERVADMIN.ERROR it's giving my a blank. Also, is there a way i can do this in a single line.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a solution that addresses one possible interpretation of your requirements (string matches on whole lines). Never use the word `pattern` as it's ambiguous - always say if you want string or regexp matches and if you want matches on whole lines (or words or whatever) or partial lines (or...) or even across lines.